# Cantor function $\sum (f_k-f_{k+1})$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

By [construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function#Iterative_construction), each $f_k$ is monotone increasing, $f_{k+1}=f_k$ on $I_j^k, j=1,2,...,2^k-1$ and $|f_k - f_{k+1}| < 2^{-k}$. Hence, $\sum (f_k-f_{k+1})$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$, and therefore $\{f_k\}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$.

What does it mean by that $\sum (f_k-f_{k+1})$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$? How the previous statements imply this uniform convergence? And why $\{f_k\}$ also converges uniformly on $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|f_k - f_{k+1}\right| \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{2^k} = 1$$
so $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (f_k - f_{k+1})$ converges uniformly by the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).

We have

$$f_1 - f_{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^n (f_k - f_{k+1}) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty] {\text{uniformly}} \sum_{k=1}^\infty (f_k - f_{k+1})$$

so $$f_{n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty] {\text{uniformly}} f_1 - \sum_{k=1}^\infty (f_k - f_{k+1})$$